# Windows Batch file "Can't find file" despite it being right there

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a .bat file to simplify the start process of ngrok.

When I tried this on a previous system, different directories etc, it worked fine.

Now I've create the batch file again to represent the new directories and it won't work.

The file I need to launch is ngrok.exe which is in the directory of `C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok` and the ngrok.exe file is in the \ngrok folder.

I need it to:

1. change directory from `C:\Users\Liam` to `C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok`
2. print and execute "ngrok -subdomain=udemy 80"
3. open the browser and point to http://udemy.ngrok.com:80
4. pause

Here is what I've written in the batch file:

```
echo
cd "C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok"

print "ngrok -subdomain=udemy 80"

timeout /t 10   
start http://udemy.ngrok.com:80

pause
```

When I double click to execute the .bat file, this is what shows in CMD

> C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok>echo ECHO is on.
>
> C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok>cd "C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok"
>
> C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok>print "ngrok -subdomain=udemy 80" Can't
>   find file ngrok -subdomain=udemy 80
>
> C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok>timeout /t 10
>
> Waiting for  7 seconds, press a key to continue ...

After this, it doesn't find the file, yet it still changes directory. It should be noted that if I enter these commands manually in CMD, it works perfectly.

Comment: `print` on Windows attempts to send the given file to a printer, which means it's looking for a file named "ngrok ...".

Comment: Ohh, I was told `print` meant to type it into the command prompt. And that worked previously. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to print the string to the command-line to execute. Just specify the program name and parameters.

I changed `echo` to `@echo off` to prevent each command from being displayed before it is executed...I'm assuming that is what you want.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ngrok"

ngrok -subdomain=udemy 80

timeout /t 10   
start http://udemy.ngrok.com:80

pause
```

Comment: Ahh thanks so much for the explanation, @aphoria.
To be honest, I actually thought echo was simply to clean the viewport up and keeping it on would let me see what was going wrong.

That command worked fine. The only problem is it starts ngrok as normal (ngrok has it's own view which takes over the cmd) and that then prevents the browser from opening the URL
![Ngrok](http://workfortheweb.com/ngrok.png).

Comment: Oh and I just found that pressing Ctrl+C (Closes ngrok), once I do this, the next command begins and it then opens the URL